# How do I make an XNOR gate work in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

By the way, I am currently on a phone, so please excuse any formatting issues, typos, or grammatical errors.
For reference: I have already looked at [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/271033/172464) thread, which seems to be the only thread on the site which references the logic gates, but it did not contain any information about the XNOR gate, specifically, and none of the proposed answers really discussed the XNOR gate at all. This question is *not* a duplicate of the linked question, as the linked question is too broad, and never directly asks about the XNOR gate, nor do any answers on that question directly explain how the XNOR gate works; my question was posted in order to allow players having issues specifically with one single gate to hopefully get help with it, whereas the other question was more aimed towards a single gate that differs completely from the gate that this question is aimed towards. Rather than marking my question as a duplicate of the other question, the two should be left up separately, and the other should be edited to remove the other gates that the poster was not actually concerned about; alternatively, the information from my question should be imported to the other question to address the XNOR gate.

I am attempting to set up a powered door in my settlement, to have an area where settlers cannot access, but I can (from my experiments I have done, it does not appear as though NPCs can actually use switches unless specifically scripted to do so, such as for missions or encounters in the wild). The problem is, I need to be able to open and close the door from both sides, and there is only one connection point on one side of the wall. I have already tried using radiating power instead of the hard connection, but it seems to require the hard connection. Even if it had worked, I would be left with basically an OR gate, where I would have to open the door from one side, flip the switch on the other side, then turn *off* the first switch, then turn off the second switch, just to get the door closed with myself on the correct side of the door. I experimented with different ways of operating this system for a few weeks, then I happened across the logic gates added by the *Contraptions Workshop* DLC. I immediately checked to see if the game had an XNOR gate (many games and logic simulators dont include this gate), and was excited when I discovered that it did, indeed, have the XNOR gate.

The XNOR gate, for anybody who does not know, is designed like those dual switch systems that many houses have for the lights in a hallway or stairway; if both switches are in the same position, the light turns on, regardless of whether the switches are in the *ON* or the *OFF* positions. If they are not in the same position (I.E., one is *ON* and the other is *OFF*), the light will turn off. This allows you to control the light from either end of a hallway, so you don't have to cross to the other side to turn you light off, then navigate your way in the dark to get back.

So, I designed an elaborate system to get the wires from one side of the wall to the other (since wires cant go *through* walls in Fallout 4; such a headache), and connected the two switches to power sources *and* to the XNOR input, and the XNOR output to the door. Nothing happened, so I checked the [Wiki](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Logic_gate) and learned that at least one, if not both, inputs have to come from another logic gate, not directly from a switch or power source. To play it safe, I connected both switches to AND gates, then the AND gates to the XNOR input. This seemed to do the trick at first glance, but then I discovered that it was still functioning like an OR gate. I double checked all my wiring, made sure there was no radiating power source that might be interfering, and even disconnected and reconnected everything. I couldn't figure it out, so I scrapped everything, went to another section of wall, away from any power source or powered object, and played around with the gates for a bit. I put two switches on the wall, wired them to AND gates, then those AND gates to the XNOR gate, and finally the XNOR output to another AND gate (I had seen a suggestion elsewhere that you might have to send the XNOR output to another logic gate rather than directly to the object you wish to power). It continued to do the same thing. Upon further inspection, it appears that the XNOR gate may have been designed incorrectly, because the game allows you to see the actual input and output values of logic gates, and as you can see in the photos linked below, the gate is functioning incorrectly (my phone refuses to upload images, so you'll have to use the links, unless someone else can put the images into my post for me; images uploaded to Imgur by a friend, as I dont have an account).
[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yxQf.jpg)

I really need assistance with this one, because I hope to use a powered door elsewhere as well, and if I cant get even this one to work then I have no idea how I'm going to secure certain areas of my settlements.

Tl;dr: XNOR gate seems to be functioning incorrectly, how do I fix it?

Comment: Respect for typing all of this on a phone.

Comment: I remember making a system to open and close a gate on both sides...needed 3 of those things and 2 switches xD

Comment: Honestly, after scouring the internet for hours, including reading the linked answer, and struggling for hours within the game itself, I've completely given up trying to get logic gates to work in Fallout 4. Bethesda really dropped the ball hard with that one. I can hardly believe these gates were made by programmers.

Comment: I literally linked that thread at the very beginning of my post and said it doesnt answer the question

Comment: I haven't played with these in the game, but logic-wise (A AND B) OR (NOT A AND NOT B) ought to do the trick. Can't you just ditch the XNOR and do that instead?

Comment: Also.... the laws of physics kind of mean that if you don't supply something, it cannot give any voltage as output. If these gates don't have supply separated from the logic functions, then they make no sense whatsoever to begin with. Do they get supply by getting mounted against a wall? Is the wall powered? Is it powered on the correct side? I don't remember how "powered walls" worked specifically, but it was a pretty shaky mechanic iirc.